# Can I determine the number of instances inside a Realm database file?

Tags: java, android, realm

Several users cannot open my app due to the size of the Realm DB being over 1 GB. I believe this is due to unclosed instances that are never compacted (probably threading issues). I am able to pull the realm file off of the device and inspect it with Realm Browser. However, I only find around 10k records. Is there any way for me to analyze the file to determine how many instances of the database are inside?

I've read that in Realm for iOS, the database file cannot be larger than the amount of memory allocated to an app. Does this same limitation apply to Android/Java? This is my hunch but I've not confirmation it. https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#general-limits

Answer (score 1):

If the app was closed, there is only ever one instance of Realm inside the file itself, namely the latest.

The size issue manifests itself in a running app where we have to keep track of the difference between the oldest and newest version. If the old version is never released in the running app, it will cause the file to balloon in size.

The reason this becomes a problem is that Realm does not automatically release this space again, but keep it for future needs. Manually calling `Realm.compactRealm(config)` will remove this space. We are in the process of adding functionality for doing this automatically: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3739

With regard to size limitations: Realm memory-map the database file. In practice, this means that older 32-bit devices will refuse to open it once the file reaches ~400 MB, but it will vary slightly depending on the device. There is no practical limit for 64-bit devices. Most new devices the last ~3 years have been 64-bit devices.